# Was ist eine Recht gegründete Organisation?

Tags: meaning

> "XXX ist eine nach deutschem Recht gegründete Agentur."

Was bedeutet dieser Satz? Was ist eine Recht gegründete Organisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wie Ingmar bereits sagte hast Du "Recht" falsch eingeordnet.

Es ist eine gängige Formulierung zu sagen, dass etwas nach "deutschem", "gültigen", "gängigem" Recht gegründet wurde.

Dies bedeutet, dass mindestens zur Zeit der Gründung die genannte Rechtslage eingehalten wurde bzw. nach der Lage nichts zu beanstanden war.

Answer (score 6):

Nicht einfach "Recht gegründet" sondern "nach deutschem Recht gegeründet", i.e. (founded) *under German law*.

Comment: Vielleicht kann man noch hervorheben, dass die Phrase `nach deutschem Recht` lautet und auch ohne `gründen` und mit anderen Verben kombiniert werden kann. Analog: `nach deutschem Reinheitsgebot gebraut`

Comment: Sorry. War die Frage schlecht? Einige geben mir minus, verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: @stardust Ich würde den Titel der Frage anpassen, nachdem klar ist, dass die eigentlich Frage etwas anders lauten sollte. Eventuell bekommst Du deswegen die down-votes.